# Combining and merging a sequence of data frames

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe, rbind

I have a sequence of n data frames, of the form:

```
n<-10 
k<-5 
d1 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:(k)) {d1 <- rbind(d1,c(a="i+1",b="i-1",c="i/1"))}
d2 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:(k+2)) {d2 <- rbind(d2,c(a="i+2",b="i-2",c="i/2"))}
d3 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:(k+3)) {d3 <- rbind(d3,c(i+3, i-3, i/3))}

...

d10 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:(k+10)) {d10 <- rbind(d10,c(i+10, i-10, i/10))}
```

I have this list of sequence of data frames that I want to merge into a single, combined data frame. I tried this:

```
total <- rbind(d1, d2,d3)
```

But got error.

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

Using other approach :

```
D <- list(d1,d2,d3)
newD <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(D)) {
  newD <- rbind(newD, cbind(frame=rep(i,length(D[[i]])),D[[i]]))
}
newD
```

But got error again.

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 5
```

It would be great to get an answer using the same approach (rbind) and a more base like approach. Both will aid in my understanding. Of course, please point out where I'm going wrong if it's obvious.

Comment: columns names (and number of columns) should be the same for all dataframes for `rbind` to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `names(df)` in this case after `rbind`ing. Each data frame you `rbind` needs to have the same column names. From `?rbind`:

> ...It then takes the classes of the columns from the first data frame, and matches columns by name (rather than by position).

So for your example, you just need to have the same column names for each data frame you `rbind`:

```
k<-5 
d1 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:(k)) {d1 <- rbind(d1,c(a=i+1,b=i-1,c=i/1)); names(d1) <- letters[1:3]}
d2 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:(k+2)) {d2 <- rbind(d2,c(a=i+2,b=i-2,c=i/2)); names(d2) <- letters[1:3]}
d3 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:(k+3)) {d3 <- rbind(d3,c(a=i+3, b=i-3, c=i/3)); names(d3) <- letters[1:3]}

> rbind(d1, d2, d3)

    a  b         c
1   2  0 1.0000000
2   3  1 2.0000000
3   4  2 3.0000000
4   5  3 4.0000000
5   6  4 5.0000000
6   3 -1 0.5000000
7   4  0 1.0000000
8   5  1 1.5000000
9   6  2 2.0000000
10  7  3 2.5000000
11  8  4 3.0000000
12  9  5 3.5000000
13  4 -2 0.3333333
14  5 -1 0.6666667
15  6  0 1.0000000
16  7  1 1.3333333
17  8  2 1.6666667
18  9  3 2.0000000
19 10  4 2.3333333
20 11  5 2.6666667
```

And a few more remarks about your example: instead of using `d1 <- rbind(d1, c(...))`, you can just do: `d1 <- data.frame(a = i + 1, b = i + 2, c = i + 3)`. And then you don't even need to rename your columns, since they all stay as is.